# Why is my return statement not working in this recursive function?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, return, tail-recursion

I have an array which is pre-sorted with only-ascending integers:

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
```

I want my program to search for an integer in that array which I'll call "gesucht" and to return the place in the array where "gesucht" is.

**I may not use any loops, packages or something like the .find method and have to use recursion**

This is my program:

```
public static int optimierteSuche(int gesucht, int[] array, int startposition, int endposition){
    if((0<=startposition && startposition<=endposition && endposition<=array.length) == false){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong input");
    }
    int m = (endposition-startposition)/2;
    if (gesucht == array[m]){
        return m;
    }
    if (array[m]<gesucht){
        optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, m+1, endposition);
    } else {
        optimierteSuche(gesucht, array,startposition, m-1);
    }

}
```

When I use the following in my main Method:

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
System.out.println(optimierteSuche(2,intArray,0,intArray.length));
```

My compiler tells me that my method is missing a return statement, although it's there and when I use my algorithm and calculate the steps myself it works (or at least I'd say it does)

I've already tried to adjust it a little, but it didn't work either:

```
public static int optimierteSuche(int gesucht, int[] array, int startposition, int endposition){
        if((0<=startposition && startposition<=endposition && endposition<=array.length) == false){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong input");
        }
        int m = (endposition-startposition)/2;
        int ergebnis = 0;
        if (gesucht == array[m]){
            ergebnis = m;
        }
        if (array[m]<gesucht){
            optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, m+1, endposition);
        } else {
            optimierteSuche(gesucht, array,startposition, m-1);
        }
        return ergebnis;
    }
```

I study economics and take some programming courses because of interest but thus do not have much contact to many others programming majors and would like some help. Thank you!

Comment: if `gesucht == array[m]` is false, then no return statement is reached.

Comment: You need to return the value from whichever of your recursive `optimierteSuche` calls is made, i.e. `return optimierteSuche(...)`

Comment: What a stupid mistake! But i got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

tgdevies is correct, credit to them, but because comments don't always express what needs to happen...

```java
public static int optimierteSuche(int gesucht, int[] array, int startposition, int endposition) {
    if ((0 <= startposition && startposition <= endposition && endposition <= array.length) == false) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong input");
    }
    int m = startposition + ((endposition - startposition) / 2);
    if (gesucht == array[m]) {
        return m;
    }
    if (array[m] < gesucht) {
        return optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, m + 1, endposition);
    }
    return optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, startposition, m - 1);
}
```

## Runnable example

```java
public class OtherTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        System.out.println(optimierteSuche(2, intArray, 0, intArray.length));
        intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        System.out.println(optimierteSuche(2, intArray, 0, intArray.length));
    }

    public static int optimierteSuche(int gesucht, int[] array, int startposition, int endposition) {
        if ((0 <= startposition && startposition <= endposition && endposition <= array.length) == false) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong input");
        }
        int m = startposition + ((endposition - startposition) / 2);
        if (gesucht == array[m]) {
            return m;
        }
        if (array[m] < gesucht) {
            return optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, m + 1, endposition);
        }
        return optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, startposition, m - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I make array { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } I get StackOverflow error though

Comment: @RichardKYu - The middle position (m) was not being calculated correctly.

Comment: @RichardKYu You'll need to debug you code to figure out why.  I think a combination of the two answers is what you're after

Comment: Yes. I got that aswell. I made m = (endposition - startposition) / 2 + startposition;

Comment: @user16320675 `startposition + ((endposition - startposition) / 2)` works, `(endposition-startposition)/2` doesn't - which is about as far as my understand stretches ;). I'm also not trying to "optimise" the solution, I was trying to "prod" the OP in the right direction to solve their immediate issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set ergebnis equal to the return value of your two calls to optimierteSuche, and fix your calculation of the middle position, and also add one more 'else', so that it looks like this:

```
public static int optimierteSuche(int gesucht, int[] array, int startposition, int endposition){
        if((0<=startposition && startposition<=endposition && endposition<=array.length) == false){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong input");
        }
        int m = startposition + ((endposition-startposition)/2);
        int ergebnis = 0;
        if (gesucht == array[m]){
            ergebnis = m;
        }
        else
        if (array[m]<gesucht){
            ergebnis=optimierteSuche(gesucht, array, m+1, endposition);
        } else {
            ergebnis=optimierteSuche(gesucht, array,startposition, m-1);
        }
        return ergebnis;
    }
```

You were almost there!